# Upgrade service fabric application (PowerShell)

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to start application upgrade using [Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt125975.aspx) command, but getting an error complaining:

> Default service descriptions must not be modified as part of upgrade. Modified default service: ...

None of the service configurations was changed. Also upgrade works fine when deployed from Visual Studio.

---

**Update:**
It turns out that parameters used in `DefaultServices` section of application manifest must be provided by `-ApplicationParameter<Hashtable>` command parameter (despite the fact they can't be changed during the upgrade).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy from Visual Studio it uses a parameter file that provides values for the application parameters defined in the application manifest. Can you check if you are providing the same value of the application parameters used in the default services section of your application manifest?

Comment: Why is this required? Documentation states that this parameter is optional. Moreover, parameters used in the default services section can't be changed during the upgrade.