# Default service descriptions can not be modified as part of upgrade set EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade to true

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to upgrade my Service Fabric application via Visual Studio.

I ended up having to use the diff package approach to ensure that only the services I change are in the upgrade.

I did this via a command file which removed the non-required files.

Now I have walked into another error which is annoying with its lack of detail:

```
Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade : Default service descriptions can not be modified as part of upgrade. Modified 
2>default service: fabric:/MYAPPLICATION/MYSERVICE. To allow it, set 
2>EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade to true.
```

Where exactly do I put this?

Please note that this is coming from Visual Studio.

I rarely get any joy using PowerShell.

I have seen references to the Update-ServiceFabricService CmdLet, but there is no more information about exactly what I need to do.

I have tried this in the application manifest without success:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ApplicationTypeName="MyServiceFabricApplication.ServiceFabricType" ApplicationTypeVersion="7.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade" DefaultValue="true" />
    <Parameter Name="MyParameter" DefaultValue="value" />
    Parameters>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="MyServiceFabricApplication.Service1.ServiceFabricPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="4.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides>
      <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
        <Settings>
          <Section Name="appSettings">
            <Parameter Name="MyParameter" Value="[MyParameter]" />
          </Section>
        </Settings>
      </ConfigOverride>
    </ConfigOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="MyServiceFabricApplication.Service2.ServiceFabricPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="2.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides>
      <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
        <Settings>
          <Section Name="appSettings">
            <Parameter Name="MyParameter" Value="[MyParameter]" />
          </Section>
        </Settings>
      </ConfigOverride>
    </ConfigOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="MyServiceFabricApplication.Service3.ServiceFabricPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="3.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides>
      <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
        <Settings>
          <Section Name="appSettings">
            <Parameter Name="MyParameter" Value="[MyParameter]" />
          </Section>
        </Settings>
      </ConfigOverride>
    </ConfigOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="MyServiceFabricApplication.Service4.ServiceFabricPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="2.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides>
      <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
        <Settings>
          <Section Name="appSettings">
            <Parameter Name="MyParameter" Value="[MyParameter]" />
          </Section>
        </Settings>
      </ConfigOverride>
    </ConfigOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="MyServiceFabricApplication.PlatformApi.ServiceFabricPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="2.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides>
      <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
        <Settings>
          <Section Name="appSettings">
            <Parameter Name="MyParameter" Value="[MyParameter]" />
          </Section>
        </Settings>
      </ConfigOverride>
    </ConfigOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="MyServiceFabricApplication.LivePriceManager.ServiceFabricPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="3.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides>
      <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
        <Settings>
          <Section Name="appSettings">
            <Parameter Name="MyParameter" Value="[MyParameter]" />
          </Section>
        </Settings>
      </ConfigOverride>
    </ConfigOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="MyServiceFabricApplication.Service5.ServiceFabricPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="3.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides>
      <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
        <Settings>
          <Section Name="appSettings">
            <Parameter Name="MyParameter" Value="[MyParameter]" />
          </Section>
        </Settings>
      </ConfigOverride>
    </ConfigOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <DefaultServices>
    <Service Name="Service1" ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="MyServiceFabricApplication.Service1.ServiceFabricType">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
    <Service Name="Service2" ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="MyServiceFabricApplication.Service2.ServiceFabricType">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
    <Service Name="Service3" ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="MyServiceFabricApplication.Service3.ServiceFabricType">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
    <Service Name="Service7" ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="MyServiceFabricApplication.Service7.ServiceFabricType">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
    <Service Name="Service5" ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="MyServiceFabricApplication.Service5.ServiceFabricType">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
    <Service Name="Service6" ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="MyServiceFabricApplication.Service6.ServiceFabricType">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
    <Service Name="Service4" ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="MyServiceFabricApplication.Service4.ServiceFabricType">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
  </DefaultServices>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, before I give you a solution, I will give a reason...

`EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade` is a flag to allow upgrading default services descriptions during application upgrades. When set to true, Default service descriptions are overwritten with new values, this is required to prevent accidental changes to the description that will cause possible failures or dataloss.

- When set to **false** (default), it will make checks to prevent failures to happen,
- When set to **true**, you assume the risk that these changes are safe

An example is when you change the number of partitions in a service and SF predict this will cause dataloss or other failures.

The fix:

`EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade` is a flag in the cluster definition, not in the service. You have to set this in your cluster manifest.

Your cluster manifest will have a section that looks like this:

```
...some stuff above...
{
  "name": "ClusterManager",
  "parameters": [
  {
    "name": "EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade",
    "value": true
  }]
  ... some more stuf below
 }
```

To change it on ***Azure***:

You can use the portal 'http://resources.azure.com' as described in [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/maheshk/2017/05/24/azure-service-fabric-error-to-allow-it-set-enabledefaultservicesupgrade-to-true/)

On ***local cluster:***

You copy the `clusterconfig.json` from the cluster installation folder, apply the changes a trigger a cluster  upgrade using the following command `Start-ServiceFabricClusterConfigurationUpgrade -ClusterConfigPath .\clusterconfig.json`

By the way...

You are using DefaultServices, you should avoid it, there are quite a few questions on SO why.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go.  My services are all stateless.  All I want to do is to be able to have my cluster upgrade without the unaffected services being closed down, they make it out as though this works out of the box nice and easy but thats not the case!  I have no idea what Default Services are, I just setup using the standard service fabric templates

Comment: For learning and development purposes are fine, you should avoid it in production because of issues like this one. On your cluster manifest, I assume the problem is because you set the instance count as a variable but does not pass as parameter in the `<parameter />` section.

Comment: ok I dont really know where to start for not using DefaultServices this is the first time I have even heard of them?

Comment: I have corrected the manifest shown here.  If I publish without doing an upgrade it all deploys fine with the correct number of instances.  One of the main things that MS always say is that you can upgrade the cluster without impacting other unchanged services that is what I am trying to do

Comment: I dont have that file on my machine? clusterconfig.json I have searched in the sfdevcluster folder and in my solution folder

Comment: sorry, the 'sfdevcluster ' store the manifest xml file after you apply the changes, you probably need the one from the SDK folder, somewhere around : `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\NonSecure\FiveNode`

Comment: I would first try to solve the problem, I don't think you should set these settings until you identify the problem, probably something on your manifest or project files are missing that is causing this issue. Take a look in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929302/upgrade-service-fabric-application-powershell

Comment: My problem is just this one my goal is to simply have the upgrade applied correctly.  Publishing new is fine I dont really have much to go on here

Comment: Im going to mark this as accepted answer thank!  Like I said I dont know anything about Default/Non default services, I will have to research that seperatly

Comment: OK, Sorry I couldn't help any better, As I suggested, you should not need this, if you need help with something else you can open a new question and I will help if I can.