# Is there a reason why EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade in Azure service fabric is not enabled as default

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Is there a reason why EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade is not enabled by default. By enabling this and updating parameters of an existing Default services and if it is stateful service will I loose data?

Comment: Did you see these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38025545/5946937 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798976/default-service-descriptions-can-not-be-modified-as-part-of-upgrade-set-enablede

Comment: the second link was usefull

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by LoekD, I've [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798976/default-service-descriptions-can-not-be-modified-as-part-of-upgrade-set-enablede) previously

`EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade` is a flag to allow upgrading default services descriptions during application upgrades. When set to true, Default service descriptions are overwritten with new values, this is required to prevent accidental changes to the description that will cause possible failures or dataloss.

Check the full answer in this question [Default service descriptions can not be modified as part of upgrade set EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798976/default-service-descriptions-can-not-be-modified-as-part-of-upgrade-set-enablede)